# Ruby CanCan ability with multiple subjects (classes)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

How to have multiple subjects to Cancan ability ?

I'd like to define ability as:

```
can :change_role, Project, Document  do |prj, doc|
   # my logic here
   ..
end
```

So i check it like this:

```
prj1 = Project.find(10)
doc1 = Document.find(...)

user.can? :change_role, prj1,  doc1
```

And it doesn't work.

But Cancan allows only this:

```
can :read, Project do |prj|
  ..
end

user.can? :read, prj1
```

Should I create my proxy class to store two subjects and pass it to ability ?

How to add abilities with multiple classes/subjects ?

Comment: Have you tried passing the [prj1, doc1] as an array  ? 
`user.can? :change_role,  [prj1,  doc1]`

Comment: yes, I tried array, it sees the ability. Seems it is the solution to define it 'can :read, Array do |a| ..'. I am concerned if it would break other abilities which expect Array.  Since it is only for action :read it wouldn't cause problems..

Comment: So  what is the problem exactly ? If you said that it sees the ability ?

Comment: it works with Array. Maybe it is another more elegant way?

Comment: Nope, that's the best way to do it, at least what is mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
user.can? :change_role, [prj1, doc1]
```

define Ability:

```
can :change_role, Array do |p|
  prj = p[0]
  doc = p[1]
  ...
end
```